# Ruby-On-Rails, See if string include numbers then remove them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run this in my rake task:

```
  if tmname.include? (/[^0-9]/i)
    tmnamenn = tmname.gsub(/[^0-9]/i, '')
  end
```

Basically if the name has a number in strip it out.

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into String
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F)** cannot compare a string with a Regexp object.

Try something like this:

```
unless tmname[/[^0-9]/].blank?
```

Another way to determine if the string contains numbers:

```
if tmname =~ /\d/
```

Comment: Aren't you being a double negative here? couldn't it be just a `tmname[/[^0-9]/].blank?`

Comment: Thanks, quickly typed out an answer. Should be edited now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use match

```
tmname.match(/[^0-9]/)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit this answer to provide information as to why your solution works and how it solves the OPs question.